# TypeError: a float is required using cv.undistortPoints function

Tags: python

I have watched on different questions on this topic but I couldn't find any solution.
I'm working on a complex array to use the function `cv.undistortPoints(src, dst, K, D, R, K).`

This is my code to have src:

```
src = np.zeros((1,1), dtype=np.complex128)
src[0,0] =  (1262, 1670)
```

But I have the following error:

> src[0,0] =  (xpos, ypos) TypeError: a float is required

Anyone has an idea to fill the complex array in order to use the function?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this question really specific to Python 2.7, or is that just the version you're running? Please edit tags as necessary.

Comment: It's just because I am using Python 2.7. Ok I'll add tags

Answer (score 0):

Try with `src[0,0] = (1262.0,1670.0)`.
By python default `1262` and `1670` are `int` and not `float`, by adding `.0` you are telling it that these are meant to be floats.